# Как увеличить расстояние между итемами в QComboBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qss

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QWidget)

import sys


class PortionStepOne(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PortionStepOne, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label_meal = QLabel('Выберите прием пищи')
        self.label_meal.setStyleSheet('''QLabel {
                                font-size: 15px;
        }''')

        self.line_meal = QFrame()
        self.line_meal.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)

        self.box_meal_time = QComboBox()
        self.box_meal_time.addItems(['Завтрак', 'Второй завтрак', 'Обед', 'Второй обед', 'Ужин',
                                     'Второй ужин', 'Перекус'])
        self.box_meal_time.setObjectName('box_meal_time')
        self.box_meal_time.setStyleSheet('''#box_meal_time {
                            font: 17px;
        }
        #box_meal_time QAbstractItemView::item {
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }
        ''')

        self.hbox_meal = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_meal.addWidget(self.box_meal_time)

        self.main_box_meal_time = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box_meal_time.addWidget(self.label_meal)
        self.main_box_meal_time.addWidget(self.line_meal)
        self.main_box_meal_time.addLayout(self.hbox_meal)
        self.main_box_meal_time.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(self.main_box_meal_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = PortionStepOne()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Кст, вы заметили, что в этом вопросе решение как и для QCompleter'а? :)

Comment: Заметил, но почему-то я подумал QStyledItemDelegate именно для QCompleter, теперь буду знать что это магия))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Магия не работает для элементов, пока не добавить [QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html):

```
self.box_meal_time.view().setItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate(self))
```

*Кст, `QAbstractItemView::item` можно сократить до `::item`*

Весь код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QWidget, QStyledItemDelegate

import sys


class PortionStepOne(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PortionStepOne, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label_meal = QLabel('Выберите прием пищи')
        self.label_meal.setStyleSheet('''
            QLabel {
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        ''')

        self.line_meal = QFrame()
        self.line_meal.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)

        self.box_meal_time = QComboBox()
        self.box_meal_time.addItems([
            'Завтрак', 'Второй завтрак', 'Обед', 'Второй обед', 'Ужин',
            'Второй ужин', 'Перекус'
        ])
        self.box_meal_time.setObjectName('box_meal_time')
        self.box_meal_time.view().setItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate(self))
        self.box_meal_time.setStyleSheet('''
            #box_meal_time {
                font: 17px;
            }
        
            #box_meal_time ::item {
                padding-bottom: 30px;
                color: red;
            }
        ''')

        self.hbox_meal = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_meal.addWidget(self.box_meal_time)

        self.main_box_meal_time = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box_meal_time.addWidget(self.label_meal)
        self.main_box_meal_time.addWidget(self.line_meal)
        self.main_box_meal_time.addLayout(self.hbox_meal)
        self.main_box_meal_time.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(self.main_box_meal_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = PortionStepOne()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]